# Aligning names within the \author command

Tags: titles

I need to present a College assignment and it has to be in `article` style. My problem is that right after the title I've got to add my professor's name and my working group. I tried this:

```
\author{\textbf{Professor:} Professor's name 
\\  \textbf{Working Group:} Member 1 \\ Member 2 \\ Member 3}
```

But the result is not visually appealing 'cause nothing is aligned and looks pretty unnatural. Is there a way to improve this presentation?

Also, I would like to add my institution's name somewhere (it's not mandatory) but I don't know how to do it with the `\maketitle` command I’m using. Any advice on this is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In the default [`article` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) the authors are set in a `t`op-aligned `tabular` (with one `c`entred column), as defined in `\@maketitle`:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}% <------
        \@author%            <------ Authors
      \end{tabular}\par}%    <------
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

As such, if you're interested in a specific alignment, set the authors using a nested `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is a title}
\author{\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \textbf{Professor:} & Professor's name \\
  \textbf{Working Group:} & Member 1 \\ & Member 2 \\ & Member 3
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, utilize the single `c`entred column in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is a title}
\author{\textbf{Professor:} \\  Professor's name \\
  \textbf{Working Group:} \\
  Member 1 \quad Member 2 \quad Member 3}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In Beamer I get `! Use of \begin doesn't match its definition.` Is there an analogous way?

Comment: @Leo: Which of the above code did you use with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)?

Comment: The one with the `\begin{tabular}{rl}`.

Comment: @Leo: This is because [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) sets the author information in the footer as well, and there must be something amiss with that translation. Since the fix might be not as easy, I suggest posting a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk), linking back to this one. Also remember to supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Thanks. I added it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166531/