# How to change author alignment in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, titles

It appears that different classes set up author layouts using tables.
I would like to render one of these outputs:

Equivalent to `\begin{tabular}{rl}`:

```
  Joe Schmoe My Boss
    Jane Doe His Boss
```

or, equivalent to `\raggedleft`:

```
  Joe Schmoe My Boss
   Jane Doe His Boss
```

from something resembling this M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{%
Joe Schmoe, My Boss%
\and
Jane Doe, His Boss%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I don't mind using `\institute` or something equivalent for job title, and I can even drop the job title to see a simple solution.

In some other document classes [there is a nice solution involving `\preauthor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21012/),
which I could modify in my style file.
Unfortunately, I get an unknown command error in Beamer 3 on `\preauthor` with that code. 
Are there equivalent constructs in Beamer?

There is also another approach [that uses a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129047/) 
but that also fails in Beamer.

Ideally, I would like to change `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default theme}{...` in my beamer style file, 
so that I could still use `\author{}` with all its trimmings in the main file,
but since I do not use authors anywhere else on the slide, 
a solution using some kind of box in the main source would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option redefining the internal `\beamer@author` defined in `beamerbasetitle.sty` (in this way, the definition will be theme-independent) to use a `tabular` with the desired alignment; you need to use the optional argument to provide a proper information for the author bookmark:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}%
  \begin{tabular}{rl}#2\end{tabular}}%
  \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
  \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
    \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
    \beamer@stripands#1 \and\relax
    {\let\inst=\@gobble\let\thanks=\@gobble\def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title}
\author[Joe and Jane]{%
Joe Schmoe, & My Boss \\
Jane Doe, & His Boss
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `\begin{tabular}{rl}` to `\begin{tabular}{r}` above for the other alignment required.

In a comment it has been requested to redefine `\and` so that it acts as `\tabularnewline` to separate author rows in the mandatory argument of `\author`; here's the required modification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\and{\tabularnewline}
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\tabularnewline}%
  \begin{tabular}{rl}#2\end{tabular}}%
  \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
  \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
    \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
    \beamer@stripands#1 \and\relax
    {\let\inst=\@gobble\let\thanks=\@gobble\def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title}
\author[Joe \and Jane]{%
Joe Schmoe, & My Boss \and
Jane Doe, & His Boss
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use `\and` instead of `\\ ` to separate authors, so that, when the template changes, the `\author` field doesn't need to change? I see that there are references to `\and` in your MWE `\def`. I tried redefining `\and`, so that it could retain its usual role in separating authors, but my changes (using `\renewcommand`) were ignored.

Comment: @Leo yes, it's possible. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Not only did that work great, but more importantly I can understand it and modify it too.